# Use principle of minimum maximum for the equation of Laplace

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Use principle of minimum maximum for te equation of Laplace, for prove the solution of the problem homogeneous is:

\begin{eqnarray}
\Delta u=0 \,\,\,\, \text{in} \,\,\Omega\atop
u=0 \,\,\,\, \text{on  }\,\, \partial\Omega
\end{eqnarray}

is the trivial solution.

I don't have a clear idea of how solve this type of exercise. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: The maximum value of $u$ on $\bar \Omega$ occurs on $\partial \Omega$.  If $u=0$ on all of $\Omega$, then what is the maximum value of $u$?

Comment: Thanks for answer @MarkViola i think the maximum value of $u$ is 0. Is correct?

Comment: Yes, of course.  And the minimum value is also $0$.